# What's the best, secure way to share some .bashrc source between users and root?

Tags: users, root, bashrc, source, shared-file

How's the best, secure way to have `/root/.bashrc` and `/home/user/.bashrc` include a common `.bash.shared` file?

In other words like this:

> **/root/.bashrc** --sources--> **.bash.shared** <--sources--
>   **/home/user/.bashrc**

If I put `.bash.shared` in `/root`, then I can't read it from home due to lack of permission because on Debian /root is set to drwx------ by default.

I don't know the security consequences of loosening restrictions on /root.  It must be that way for a reason.  *(In other words, I would have to give /root drwx-----x).*

I think one possible workaround, would be to put `.bash.shared` in some other root owned folder that both root and users can read, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this, or if loosening the permissions on /root is safe?

---

*(Out of fear, and as I've been learning linux, I've kept two separate identical files: `/root/.bash.shared` and `/home/user/.bash.shared`, thinking that at some point I would stumble on a good solution to this.  It's a pain to remember to always update the other when I edit the one.  So I want to fix this one way or another, but without a security hole.)*

Thanks!

Comment: What's your threat model?

Comment: Not for nothing but /root is locked down universally across most (if not all) unix/linux variants  for a good reason.  I would avoid at all costs changes those permissions.

Comment: @Michael, nothing special, just that tons of machines are taking on water every year now. nuf said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly common practice and the usual standard is to store this common file somewhere in `/etc` (such as `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.)

For instance, RHEL/CentOS ship a `/etc/bashrc` and both root's and the default users' `.bashrc` contains this snippet:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

The file is, of course, owned by root. But readable by all (needs to be, if non-root users are going to source it.)

It's important that only root can modify it, since otherwise a user with write access would be able to add commands to this file that would be executed by root next time root logs in... not good! But I guess you expected that already...