# Best way to source config file inside sudo user .bashrc file?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, chmod

I'm building a LEMP stack script powered by bash scripts and CLI aliases. For security reasons, all of the bash scripts, and the stack config file (also bash syntax) are owned by `root:root`.

I added some bash alias commands for easier management inside the sudo user `.bashrc` file to save keystrokes when the sudo user wants to run a bash script.... these work great, however, I'd like to expand these by allowing certain alias commands to integrate with variable options defined in the stack config file.

For example, `SITE_NOINDEX` is defined in the config file owned by `root:root` and maybe I want to have a bash alias available to the sudo user to view this option's value.

The problem is  that the config file is chmod `0700` for security reasons, and it seems the easiest fix is to change all the bash scripts and config file to `0740` and either add the sudo user [to group "root"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713283/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-add-users-to-the-root-group) or change the ownership of all scripts to be something less secure like `root:sudo` which seems a little bit goofy... is there a better solution here?

Edit: currently `Permission denied` error is given if I try to simply `source` the stack config file inside sudo user's `.bashrc` file (after trying to restart bash session). The rest of the normal aliases work fine but none of the shell variables in the config file are readable with current permissions.

Related: [How to secure a sudo - powered script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295422/how-to-secure-a-sudo-powered-script)

Related: [What's the best, secure way to share some .bashrc source between users and root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433191/whats-the-best-secure-way-to-share-some-bashrc-source-between-users-and-root)

Comment: Also adding that I can't (or don't want) to create yet another "shared bashrc" file with relaxed permissions for both "root" and "sudo" users to share as per the linked question, because it adds more work and confusion, esp. when I'm setting this up for new companies. I'm trying to keep things simple and only define variables a single time in the config file.

Comment: You don’t want a split `.bashrc`, which is understandable; but how about a split configuration file? You’d have one with root-only settings (`root:root`, permissions 0700), and one with non-confidential settings (`root:root` still, but permissions 0755).

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt and yes, I'm afraid that might be the only solution besides adding the sudo user to the `root` group (or root user to `sudo` group)... neither one is deal. It either breaks "single source of truth" or requires messy user groups!